# Facebook post via API - include html, css, & outside images?

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First off: I'm a designer, I'm not a developer. I don't really know php or JS, I know html and css. And that's not changing.

Context: I'm working on designing a website for a client that once it is turned over to the development team will involve using the facebook API to allow users to post things on their facebook walls. I'm not familiar with the facebook API at all and I don't really use facebook. However, I need to know the limitations of these things so I can actually design something that is possible to develop. I tried looking at the facebook API docs, but it's gibberish to me since I'm not a developer.

My actual question: I know text can be added, I know at least one main image can be added to go with the post. Can any custom html/css be added to the content of a facebook post? Specifically the client asked for the stars system on the website to the facebook posts (which would require custom html, css, and images from the site), but after working with the facebook share button/iframe I doubt facebook allows for that type of thing.

And if you don't mind posting a long answer: is there any control over what the post looks like, is that all set by facebook? Things like sizes of images, placement of content, etc. Or is this just another insert iframe (maybe with a few variables) and facebook has 100% control over what goes inside the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't control over what the post looks like using Facebook Graph API. Publishing a post only supports the following fields:

> - **message**: The main body of the post, otherwise called the status    message. Either link or message must be supplied.
> - **link**: The URL of a link to attach to the post. Either link or message    must be supplied.
> - **actions**: The action links attached to the post.
> - **place**: Page ID of a location associated with this post.
> - **tags**: Comma-separated list of user IDs of people tagged in this post.
> - **privacy**: Determines the privacy settings of the post.
> - **object_attachment**: Facebook ID for an existing picture in the    person's photo albums to use as the thumbnail image.

Source: [Graph API User Feed Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/#publish).

As you can see, there is no field to customize the design/template of the post. In short, what you publish using the Graph API will just look like a typical post that you post using Facebook GUI.